# Email an Access 2007 report automatically every night with no user action

Tags: ms-access

I have a report in MS Access 2007 and I would like to send this report as pdf automatically every night without asking a user to run the macro manually or so. I have the following code in a macro:

```
    Dim strRecipient As String
    Dim strSubject As String
    Dim strMessageBody As String

    strRecipient = "emailaddr...@domain.com"
    strSubject = "This is the email subject"
    strMessageBody = "Here is a whole bunch of interesting text to accompany the   attachment."

    DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "rptNameofReport", acFormatPDF, strRecipient, , ,  strSubject, strMessageBody, False
```

In google, it says I can then name this macro as autoexec and use windows task scheduler. However, this does not work in my case becase when I run the code above, I get a security warning message from outlook saying "a program is trying to automatically send email on your behalf
do you want to allow this? if this is unexpected it may be virus and you should choose no"

I don't want this message to appear because I don't want a confirmation from a user since the plan is to send this email automatically at night. Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found so far to do this is to make alterations on a user's PC on their version of MS Outlook to allow this bypass since the error is attached and run through outlook, not Access.  Here is an article outlining a way to acheive this:

http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Outlook-Send-E-mail-Without-Security-Warning

A little in depth but does the job.  Hopefully this helps!  Unfortuantely because of the security model, you cannot just disable it and have to go a little further to allow this type of behavior on a user's machine.  The annoying part is setting this up on each user machine if this is going to fire on each machine rather than a central place on the server somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) to avoid that Outlook security warning.

Also naming the macro "autoexec" means that Access will attempt to run the macro every time the database is opened.  As an alternative, you could give the macro a different name, say "mcrMidniteEmail", then use the **/x** [command-line switch](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209207) in the task scheduler.

```
/x mcrMidniteEmail
```

**Edit**: If you have a GMail account available, you can also use VBA to send email through that account using SMTP ... without involving Outlook.  See [Sending Google Mail (Gmail) from MS Access, VBA, Excel, Word...](http://msaccesshintsandtips.ning.com/profiles/blogs/sending-google-mail-gmail-from)

Comment: Thanks HansUp! I am using a computer/email for my company so I have to use outlook.

Comment: OK, if GMail is out, look at Outlook Redemption.

Answer (score 1):

Following code always worked for me.

```
Sub CDO_Mail_Small_Text(Mailto, MailCC, Mailtext, Optional Subject = "", Optional Attachment = "")
Dim iMsg As Object
Dim iConf As Object
Dim strbody As String
Dim Flds As Variant

Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

    iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
    Set Flds = iConf.Fields
    With Flds
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") _
                       = "mail.Mybusiness.com"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
        .Update
    End With

strbody = "Enter the Email body."

With iMsg
    Set .Configuration = iConf
    .To = Mailto
    .cc = MailCC
    .BCC = ""
    .From = """Do Not Reply "" <NoReply@MyBusiness.com>"
    If Subject = "" Then
    .Subject = "EMail Subject"
    Else
    .Subject = Subject
    End If
    .TextBody = Mailtext
    If Attachment <> "" Then .AddAttachment Attachment
    .send
End With

Set iConf = Nothing
Set iMsg = Nothing

End Sub
```

Of course you could make this code work with gmail or other email servers.

Comment: Hi THEn, thanks for your reply! This seems to be an easy solution. I tried to run it but I get an error saying: "Ambiguous name detected CDO_Mail_Small_Text". I added the CDO library reference but still the same issue. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Maybe you already have same variable or function "CDO_Mail_Small_Text" try to make this sub as private and see if you have same function elsewhere.

Comment: Isn't CDO being phased out as a standard Windows component?

Comment: Thank you THEn! you are right! I don't get that error msg anymore. However, I don't see the statement that is supposed to send the report as pdf in your code? There is a report in the same Access db that I need to email it. If I am correct, your code sends a text body but no report attached to it.Thoughts?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that in this code I create PDF file using PDF Printer before sending an email.

Comment: Is there a way we can send an existing report as PDF using your code? Thanks alot!

Comment: I have PDF printer installed and using this pdf printer I create the PDF file then I use this code to send an email.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a Forms 'On Timer' event in conjunction with the 'Timer interval' to call the nightly routine that prepares and sends the email.  Just include conditional code to verify that it's time to send the email.  Some corporate environments lock down the Windows Task Scheduler, so this is a viable option.